# How to extract coefficients from my equation of: x^3 - 60x^2 + 1100x - 6000 / -6000?

Tags: python, sympy

Given an array of integers, I am trying to extract the coefficient in front of each `"x^i"`, ...., `"x^3"`, `"x^2"`, `"x"`.

Given the equation `v(x) = (x-x0)(x-x1)...(x-x(i-1)) / (xi-x0)(xi-x1)...(xi-x(i-1))`

For example if given array is [30, 20, 10, 0] then the expected result will be:

`x^3 - 60x^2 + 1100x - 6000 / -6000`

I am nearly there I just need to find a way to obtain `1, -60, 1100, -6000` from the numerator.

I've been trying various split methods but it did not seem to work.

My current code:

```
from sympy import *

def extract_coeff(array):
    coeff = []

    x=Symbol('x')
    count = 0
    for item in array:
        if item != 0:
            count = count + 1

    total = len(array)
    list = []

    numerator_list = []
    numerator = 1
    denom_list = []
    denom = 1

    for i in range(total):
        list.append(array[i])

    for item in list:
        denom_list.append((list[-1] - item))

    denom_list.pop()

    for item in denom_list:
        denom = denom * item

    # numerator
    for item in array:
        if item != 0:
            numerator = numerator * (x-item)

    numerator = expand(numerator)

    print(numerator)
    numerator = str(numerator)

    # store coefficient
    if numerator[0] == 'x':
        coeff.append(1)

    # trying to split (PLEASE HELP)
    numerator = numerator.replace('+ ', ', ')
    print(numerator.split(', '))

extract_coeff([30,20,10,0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify, with a well formatted example what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you check your equation v(x)? I don't think it is correct. Notice that for an array arr of len(arr)=i, you cannot have arr[i] because the index will be out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have an equation

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> eq = (x**3 - 60*x**2 + 1100*x - 6000) / -6000
```

And you want to look at the numerator. If you are sure there are no compound fractions then `numer(eq)` will work. If there might be more than one term as in `x/3 + x` then use `as_numer_denom()`

```
>>> n, d = eq.as_numer_denom()
```

Now convert the numerator `n` to a Poly and ask for all coefficients:

```
>>> Poly(n).all_coeffs()
[-1, 60, -1100, 6000]
```

Since the denominator was negative, that negative sign is now in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!